Specify different CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD for unit tests
I have a program that requires in its top-level CMakeLists.txt:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

This cannot be touched. I introduced unit tests to this project using the catch2 framework, and created an integration tests that requires std::filesystem. But this requires a higher C++ standard.
So I added into tests/CMakeLists.txt:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(headers
  catch.hpp
  )

set(source  
  main.cpp
  date_test.cpp
  climate_test.cpp
)
...

But this does not do the trick. Is this even something that is possible? Or do you have another suggestion? Apparently it would take much effort to have people upgrade their C++ so I can raise the version everywhere. But the tests are important and I want them to run on our CI server.
Thanks for any hints!

CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is only the default value. The version can be set specific for each target with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD

Please post as an answer, then I can accept it, this solved it, thank you!!!

So you are testing with different compiler options than what is used in production? Is that a great idea? What will the tests show?

Valid remark. Unfortunately we have people that do not want to update their C++ versions. The tests are not even run at all for those compiler versions and no one has used tests at all in the project. I have now added them. So I think it's better than nothing, because I also did not manage to write a proper integration test without using filesystem stuff. If anything, I hope this pushes people to finally upgrade to newer C++ versions. What do you think?

The CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD variable is (like many other CMAKE_* variables) only the default value for target-specific settings.
So it is indeed possible to set the C++ standard for a single target to a different value.
As documented here, the following line does the trick:
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
PS: As pointed out in the comments you should think about the question, if it is a good idea to run the tests with another C++ version than the code itself.

Just using set will be not be sufficient in this case. However, you can assign things such as CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to each target individually using:
set_property(TARGET FooLib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

Where FooLib would be the target for your tests.

As BoP pointed out in the comments, it is probably not a good idea to use different compiler options in your tests than your production code though, since the tests might show different results due to the compiler options.
